# How to enable bluetooth in 18.04 ubuntu?

Tags: bluetooth

I am currently using ubuntu 18.04 and unable to enable the bluetooth while attending the meetings. Can anyone suggest any particular way of enabling the bluetooth on my device?

However, it shows plug in a dongle to use bluetooth.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDofn.png)

[image]

Comment: I will ask and you know for sure you have Bluetooth hardware?

Comment: I don't know could you please tell me how to check that in ubuntu?

Comment: @robertfroast `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: What is "your device"?